# How to include desktop file and icon in a postmarketos package?

Tags: icons, desktop-application, alpine-linux

I am working on a GUI app for postmarket os that I wish to distribute via apk. I have successfully packaged the app using apkbuild, but after a day of searching, I cannot find any info on including a desktop file and icon image in the package. Does anyone have any information on how to accomplish this?

I am very new to postmarket os and alpine linux, so any help would be appreciated.